# dynamic menu with Ajax

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I am creating a dynamic menu of users from the database. When the user clicks on the profile I need that profile highlighted. Here is the menu of the profiles. My menu works great, I need help on how to get the elements of the menu highlighted. Thanks for the help.

```
function childMenu(profileId){

var path = location.pathname;

    $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '',                  //the script to call to get data          
    data: "method=getChildProfile&profileId="+profileId,  //requirements 
    dataType: 'xml',                        //data format      
    success: function(xml)     
    {  
    $(xml).find('Child').each(function()
    {   
    var proId = $(this).attr('profileId');
    var lName = $(this).find('lName').text();
    var fName = $(this).find('fName').text();

    $("#childMenu").append("<li><a href='"+path+"?child="+proId+"&fName="+fName+"&lName="+lName+"'></a></li>");

    });
    }
    });

}
```

Comment: how are you "highlighting" the menu? By adding a class? If so, you can use the class as a selector $('li.highlight'). It would help if you could post the html of whole menu.

Comment: my html: 
<div id="side_nav">
<ul name="childMenu" id="childMenu">
</ul>    
</div>
I am a newbie, so I have no Idea where to start to get the profile selected to highlight.

Comment: check out my answer if it works for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm getting you right: (If it's not what you're looking for comment and I'll edit my answer)

Edit the append line:

```
$("#childMenu").append("<li><a href='"+path+"?child="+proId+"&fName="+fName+"&lName="+lName+"' onClick='javascript:doHighlight(this)'>???</a></li>");
```

Add a new function to your JS:

```
function doHighlight(elem)
{
 if(elem.className == "highlighted")
   elem.className = "";
 else
   elem.className = "highlighted";
}
```

And add a class to your css:

```
.highlighted{
 background-color:yellow;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, and I tried both. Both highlight the selected menu item, BUT it is not staying highlighted. when the page loads the highlight goes away. any suggestions to make it stay, until a new profile is selected?

Comment: Oh, now I got you. You should use `sessions` or adding a new parameter to your link so you'll know which profile was highlighted before.

Comment: How would I go about that? like I said I am new to Ajax.

Comment: Try this tutorial: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html
The idea is to create a cookie in the doHightlight function with the id of the element. Add in your script another function that will check for that cookie and highlight the desired element.

Answer (score 1):

After you have your menu built, you need to add a click event handler which will highlight your `<li>`

```
$('#childMenu li').click(function() {
    $('#childMenu li.selected').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
});
```

then you can get your selected `<li>` with

```
$('#childMenu li.selected')
```

you can also edit your .select css class to change the background color and whatever else you need.